# SwiftUI Sheet Crash with Occasional Warning about Modifying State

Tags: macos, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI button that, when clicked, a `sheet` displays a confirmation modal. When a button is clicked in that modal to confirm, I make a save to Core Data.

I'm getting one or all of a few nasty results:

- The sheet just hangs and becomes unresponsive.
- I get a warning: *"Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior"*.
- I get a crash.

Obviously I'm modifying the state becomes I'm deleting a thing, but I'm unclear on how to do this right.

Here is my view where I click delete:

```
struct MyView: View{
  @State var showDeleteModal = false

  var body: some View{
    Button("Delete"){
      showDeleteModal.toggle()
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: self.$showDeleteModal) {
      ModalView(confirm: {
        self.showDeleteModal.toggle()
        //Save the object in my Core Data stuff
        model.saveThing(thing: thing)
      })
    }
  }
}
```

And here's my modal that has a callback function to confirm the deletion:

```
struct ModalView: View {
  var confirm:() -> Void
  
  var body: some View { 
    Button("Confirm"){
      confirm()
    }
  }
}
```

How do I hide the modal and make the save (which removes the view from the screen) without interfering with SwiftUI's state?

Comment: Does wrapping the `model.saveThing` in `DispatchQueue.main.async` help? (just guessing on this one)

Comment: No, I actually had tried that and still get the crash.

Comment: I should probably add that `MyView` is a child view that contains a specific Core Data object. Its parent is the list of objects. It seems the crash is happening because I'm deleting a child from within itself.

Comment: You can try with this ``` @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode``` and on button click ```  presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()``` for ModalView.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using `sheet(isPresented:onDismiss:content:)` and calling `model.saveThing` in `onDismiss`:

```
struct MyView: View {
    @State var showDeleteModal = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("Delete") {
            showDeleteModal.toggle()
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: self.$showDeleteModal, onDismiss: onDismiss) {
            ModalView()
        }
    }
    
    func onDismiss() {
        model.saveThing(thing: thing)
    }
}
```

Then you can dismiss the sheet without knowing the parent's state - just use `@Environment(\.presentationMode)`:

```
struct ModalView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode

    var body: some View {
        Button("Confirm") {
            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

Note: as sheet can be closed without interacting with the confirm button, you can detect how it was closed using another `@State` variable - see:

- [SwiftUI: How to show an alert after a sheet is closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63968480/8697793)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This all makes sense. I should have mentioned that this is in a macOS app, and it appears `onDismiss` never gets called in a macOS sheet (which is probably a bug). I think that since `MyView` is what is getting deleted, the issue might persist even if `onDismiss` worked correctly. I may just have to find a different UI approach to confirm deletion that doesn't involve a `sheet`.